# Duas classes mapeando a mesma tabela com o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, classes, asp.net-identity, entidade-relacionamento

Estou tentando fazer o `entity` mapear duas classes para a mesma tabela isso é possivel?

***Cenário:***

Meu `identity` esta desacoplado (tuto do Eduardo Pires) do meu domínio e da camada de apresentação na camada de domínio tenho uma classe `usuario` que eu gostaria de representar a tabela `AspNetUsers`, porem quando referencio a classe `usuario` no context (`DBSet<usuario>`) e mando o `migrations` atualizar tudo ele me mostra o seguinte erro:

> `The entity types 'Usuario' and 'IdentityUser' cannot share table 'AspNetUsers' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.`

Já rodei de todas as formas, mas, não obtive sucesso, alguém pode dar uma luz?

Comment: Isso que você está tentando fazer, não funciona, e o erro diz que não há uma hierarquia de relação entras elas.

Comment: Opa... Vlw pela rapidez.... E por acaso eu consigo converter o applicationUser para ser recebido pela minha classe usuario????

Comment: também não, o que você precisa fazer?

Comment: Implementar uma interface com alguns metodos especificos para tratar os dados do usuario.

Comment: Entao, implementei fazendo referencia direta ao contexto do identity... sei q nao eh muito elegante mas funcionou... vlw pela boa vontade em ajudar...

Answer (score 1):

se está utilizando `Identity` não deve utilizar `DbSet<Usuarios>`

e sim  `db.Users`.